# How to export named version data of google spreadsheet to local machine

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I tried below methods to export named version data of google spreadsheet to local machine, but not able to find any method to do so. I am able to get revision id.

```
Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
            File file = driveService.files().get(spreadsheetId).execute();
            
            RevisionList revisions = driveService.revisions().list(spreadsheetId).execute();
            List<Revision> revisionList = revisions.getRevisions();
```

Get data Range.

```
ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
        .get(spreadsheetId, range)
        .execute();
```

How to retrieve values by revision id.